# Flattening nested hash to an array

Tags: ruby

I'd like to flatten nested hash to an array. For example:

```
a = {'1'=>{'2'=>{'5'=>{},'6'=>{'8'=>{}}}},'3'=>{},'4'=>{'7'=>{}}}
```

and result of flatten_nested_hash(a) would be:

```
["1", "2", "5", "6", "8", "3", "4", "7"]
```

Finally I wrote some recursive function, but I feel that there must be some easier, non-recursive way of doing it.

My function looks like this:

```
  def flatten_nested_hash(categories)
    categories.map do |k,v|
      if v == {} 
        k
      else
        [k,flatten_nested_hash(v)]
      end
    end.flatten
  end
```

Comment: @raam86 PHP and Ruby are completely different languages. There may be a duplicate somewhere, but definitely not that one.

Comment: @Mischa I completely agree. Must say I was too lazy to generate the comment myself. Fixed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047106/getting-to-the-bottom-of-a-multidimensional-array-of-objects Can give another perspective on this question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recursive.

```
def flatten_nested_hash(categories)
  categories.flat_map{|k, v| [k, *flatten_nested_hash(v)]}
end
```

Defining it on the Hash class.

```
class Hash
  def flatten_nested; flat_map{|k, v| [k, *v.flatten_nested]} end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

With Ruby 2.1 and later you can use refinements to add a method to `Hash` and expose it only to the modules / classes you need.

```
module HashRefinements
  refine Hash do
    def flatten_nested
      flat_map { |k, v| [k, *v.flatten_nested] }
    end
  end
end
```

In your class / module

```
class MyThing
  using HashRefinements

  ...

  def flatten_categories
    categories.flatten_nested
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a nested data structure - you're going to have to use some kind of recursive or iterative method to extract all the keys. That's a bit easier than what you have, though:

```
def deep_extract_keys(hash)
  hash.keys + hash.values.flat_map {|value| deep_extract_keys value }
end

p deep_extract_keys({"1"=>{"2"=>{"5"=>{}, "6"=>{"8"=>{}}}}, "3"=>{}, "4"=>{"7"=>{}}})
```

This is a breadth-first search, rather than a depth-first search, so the output is:

```
["1", "3", "4", "2", "5", "6", "8", "7"]
```

Comment: That changes the order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is not (explicitly) recursive and works only for non-negative integer keys:

```
a.to_s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)   # [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 3, 4, 7]
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
module Flattener
  def deep_flatten
    flatten.map do |item|
      case item
      when Hash, Array
        item.deep_flatten
      else
        item
      end
    end.flatten
  end
end

class Hash

  include Flattener

end

class Array

  include Flattener

end
```